# How to convert ruamel.yaml to dict with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I want a `dict` (or `OrderedDict`) from `ruamel.yaml`.
I am using Python 3.8, happy to switch to 3.9 if that helps.

```py
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(self.filename) as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
    print(type(data))  # <class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMapItemsView'>

    data = dict(yaml.load(f))
    print(type(data))  # <class 'dict_items'>

    data = yaml.load(f).items()  # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried it with this example,

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

with open("test.yaml") as f:
    yaml = YAML()
    data = yaml.load(f)
    print(type(data))
    print("all: ", data)
    print(dict(data)) 
    print(dict(data)['data'])
```

test.yaml

```
---
data: name
test1:
  - name: name1
```

---

Output

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap'>
all:  ordereddict([('data', 'name'), ('test1', [ordereddict([('name', 'name1')])])])
{'data': 'name', 'test1': [ordereddict([('name', 'name1')])]}
name
```

You need to load YAML into a variable before use it so, you will need to use `data` instead of `yaml.load(f)`.
It shows the error with `print(dict(yaml.load(f)))`

If you don't have to round-trip, alternatively you can use the safe loader:

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
data = yaml.load(Path('test.yaml'))
print(type(data))
```

This will load all mappings as `dict`s and sequences as `list`s instead of more complicated types for round-tripping.

Comment: Turns out my problem was due to a property defined on a superclass and redefined in a subclass that contained the code I showed. The code I posted had all the self references removed. The property's setter code was doing bad things to the data. Anyway, your answer is correct so I give this to you. Thanks!

Comment: I added an example without the need for conversion, and update the file extension to `.yaml` as that has been the recommended one since Sep 2006

Comment: @Anthon, I appreciate your response. The docs (which I believe you wrote) do not define "round trip", but I suppose that means loading/deserialzing/reserializeing/saving back to disk. My use case is in fact to load and save any changes. I was unaware that load accepted a Path, which simplifies the required code. You mention a safe loader, but that does not mean the load invocation is different, it means the constructor is different, correct? What would saving look like? My code uses `with open` but perhaps again a Path is possible?

Comment: @MikeSlinn I'll more formally define round-trip in the doc, thanks for pointing that out. I think of it as load-modify-save, while preserving most. The pure safe mode will discard comments etc, but so will casting to `dict()` for the item cast (not necessarily for the nested dict that doesn't get converted).. You can use a `Path` with `yaml.dump()` it will open the file for writing for you.

Comment: `pure=True` should be `True` by default